# Nexus 7 2012 Lolipop screen cast problem

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, chromecast

I have a first generation (2012) Nexus 7 running Android 5.0. There is a screen cast feature in the popup settings, but when I try to setup my Chromecast it is not working and cannot detect it. Does this device support screen casting?

Answer (score 1):

According to an article from July, the first gen Nexus 7 does not support screen casting to the Chromecast.

http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/07/10/hands-on-video-android-new-screen-casting-game-changer-and-more/

That information MIGHT be out of date but as of four months ago, the 2nd gen (2013) was the only Nexus 7 that was supported for screen casting